# iterated integrals of $f(x,y)=1-\frac{1}{q}\space \text{if} \space x=p/q $ contd

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ $f(x,y)=1-\frac{1}{q}\space  \text{if} \space x=p/q \space \text{where} \space p,q\in \mathbb{N} \text{are relatively prime and y is rational}$

otherwise $f(x,y)=1 $

a) Show that $f$ is integrable

b) show that the iterated integrals may not exist

The part a) was similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479965/fx-1-q-for-x-p-q-is-integrable) and adapting  a similar method as coffeemath did we can show $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$$ for some partition P

For the second part $\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy=f(x,y)$ so the integral clearly exists so by the fubini theorem  $$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy\right)dx=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx$$ the above  exists .This would then mean that $\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx$ exists and thus again the other iterated integral $\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx\right)dx$ exists contradicting what we were asked to prove .Where am I wrong